# Instruct DNS resolver to query specific DNS server for DNS records

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6, ipv4

Is it possible to instruct the configured DNS resolver to query a specific DNS server for DNS records?

The environment only allows DNS requests to a specific IPv4 (the DNS resolver) - other UDP/53 packets get dropped.

I haven't registered any domain name for my DNS server, so I would like to specify it by IPv4 address.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it depends on the software running on the resolver.

Many caching resolvers (Unbound, dnsmasq, BIND 9) *do* support this feature; often under two different names ('forward zones' point to the next resolver, and 'stub zones' point to an authoritative server, but the former seems to work in any case).

For example, Unbound's (partial) configuration would look like:

```
forward-zone:
    name: "dn42."
    forward-addr: 172.23.0.53

forward-zone:
    name: "20.72.in-addr.arpa."
    forward-addr: 172.23.0.53
```